# How to mock MinIO in NestJS/Typescript automated tests?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs, minio

I'm developing an application in NestJS. This application uses MinIO to store documents in place of Amazon's S3. The application runs inside docker containers, using docker composer, and consists of a NestJS backend (with MinIO client), a PostgreSQL database and a MiniIO server.

When running the automated tests, I replace the PostgreSQL database with SQLite in memory instead of mocking the database functions, which is much simpler to implement and less error prone.

Could I do something similar with MiniIO? I would like to have a way to run MiniIO in memory, or to simulate its operation in some way, so that the tests do not depend on an external MiniIO server.

The service I want to test:

```js
import { Injectable, UnprocessableEntityException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Client } from 'minio';
import * as path from 'path';

export type CloudStorageConfigs = {
  endPoint: string;
  bucketName: string;
  port: number;
  useSSL: boolean;
  accessKey: string;
  secretKey: string;
};

@Injectable()
export class CloudStorageService {
  private readonly client: Client;

  constructor(private readonly configs: CloudStorageConfigs) {
    this.client = new Client(configs);
  }

  async save(file: Express.Multer.File[], directory?: string) {
    await Promise.all(file.map((file) => this.saveSingleFile(file, directory)));
    return true;
  }

  private async saveSingleFile(file: Express.Multer.File, directory?: string) {
    const filename = this.getUniqueFilename(file);
    const objectName = path.join(directory, filename);
    const buffer = Buffer.from(file.buffer);
    if (!(await this.client.bucketExists(this.configs.bucketName))) {
      await this.client.makeBucket(this.configs.bucketName);
    }
    await this.client.putObject(this.configs.bucketName, objectName, buffer);
    return true;
  }

  async list(directory: string) {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const objects: string[] = [];
      const objectsStream = this.client.listObjectsV2(
        this.configs.bucketName,
        directory,
        false,
      );
      objectsStream.on('data', (obj) => {
        objects.push(obj.name || obj.prefix);
      });
      objectsStream.on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
      objectsStream.on('end', () => {
        resolve(objects);
      });
    });
  }

  async delete(objects: string[]) {
    await this.client.removeObjects(this.configs.bucketName, objects);
    return true;
  }

  private getUniqueFilename(file: Express.Multer.File): string {
    if (!file?.originalname) {
      throw new UnprocessableEntityException('File not defined');
    }
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    const tokens = file.originalname.split('.');
    let ext;
    if (!tokens || tokens.length < 2) {
      ext == '';
    } else {
      ext = '.' + tokens[tokens.length - 1];
    }
    const filename = `${uniqueSuffix}${ext}`;
    return filename;
  }
}
```

File storage module:

```js
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
    import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
    import { join } from 'path';
    import {
      CloudStorageConfigs,
      CloudStorageService,
    } from './services/file/cloud-storage.service';
    
    @Module({
      imports: [
        MulterModule.register({
          // dest: './uploads',
        }),
        ServeStaticModule.forRoot({ rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'public') }),
      ],
    })
    export class CloudStorageModule {
      static forRoot(storageConfigs: CloudStorageConfigs) {
        return {
          module: CloudStorageModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: CloudStorageService,
              useValue: new CloudStorageService(storageConfigs),
            },
          ],
          exports: [CloudStorageService],
        };
      }
    }
```

Image module (uses file storage module):

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CloudStorageModule } from '../cloud-storage/cloud-storage.module';
import { MinioCongifs } from '../cloud-storage/configs/minio/minio.congifs';
import { ImageController } from './controller/image.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CloudStorageModule.forRoot({
      endPoint: MinioCongifs.endpoint,
      port: MinioCongifs.port,
      useSSL: MinioCongifs.useSSL,
      accessKey: MinioCongifs.accessKey,
      secretKey: MinioCongifs.secretKey,
      bucketName: MinioCongifs.bucketName,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [ImageController],
  providers: [],
})
export class ImageModule {}
```

Where the modules for test are generated:

```js
export async function getTestingModule(
  additionalMetadata?: ModuleMetadata,
): Promise<TestingModule> {
  return await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ UserEntity ]),
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
      TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'sqlite',
        database: ':memory:',
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
      }),
      PassportModule,
      JwtModule.register({
        secret: JWTConfigs.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: JWTConfigs.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION             },
      }),
      ...(additionalMetadata?.imports || []),
    ],
    providers: [
      AppService,
      AuthenticationService,
      EncryptionService,
      JwtStrategy,
      LocalStrategy,
      RefreshTokenRepository,
      TokenService,
      UserService,
      CloudStorageService,
      ...(additionalMetadata?.providers || []),
      { provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: JwtAuthenticationGuard },
      { provide: APP_GUARD, useClass: RolesGuard },
    ],
    controllers: [
      AppController,
      AuthenticationController,
      UserController,
      ImageController,
      ...(additionalMetadata?.controllers || []),
    ],
  }).compile();
}
```